# How to increment in forloop in random iterations?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, random, counter

I'm trying to add a random amount of "boulder" data into my "location" data. I want to use forloop to generate a random amount of boulders to put into each "location". I can't seem to get if I should use forEach or forLoop. In essence I want to know how to generate a forloop that increments in random iterations. (i.e. index=0, randomNum = 5 => nextIndex = 0+5, randomNum = 3, thirdIndex = 5+3 and so on)

here's my randomNum generator

```
const randomNum = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}
```

and this is my boulder setting random forLoop (which doesnt work)

```
const allBoulders = async() => {await Boulder.find().exec()}

for (i=0, i < allBoulders.length; i+=upperCount;) {
    console.log(i)
    const area = location.area;
    const place = location.place;
    const latitude = location.latitude;
    const longitude = location.longitude;
    const boulderLocation = new Location({area: area, place: place, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude});
    const upperCount = indexCount + randomNum(1, 5)
    const boulderSet = allBoulders.slice(indexCount, upperCount);
    boulderLocation.boulders.push(...boulderSet);
    // await boulderLocation.save()
    console.log(boulderLocation)
    indexCount = upperCount;
};
```

I'm getting the error:

```
for (i=0, i < allBoulders.length; i+=upperCount;) {
                                     ^

ReferenceError: upperCount is not defined
```

any help will be greatly appreciated!! thanks in advance!

UPDATE[SOLVED]:
I got it working thanks to answer from swift-lynx

```
locations.forEach(async(location) => {
    const allBoulders =  await Boulder.find().exec()
    // console.log(foundAllBoulders);
    for (let i = 0; i < allBoulders.length;) {
        const area = location.area;
        const place = location.place;
        const latitude = location.latitude;
        const longitude = location.longitude;
        const boulderLocation = new Location({area: area, place: place, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude});
        const random = randomNum(1, 5);
        const upperCount = i + random;
        const boulderSet = allBoulders.slice(i, upperCount);
        boulderLocation.boulders.push(...boulderSet);
        // await boulderLocation.save()
        console.log(boulderLocation);
        i += random;
    }
})
```

i used a forEach so that i can call the async function, placed a forloop where the randomNum is generated in the loop with i, being iterated from the same randomNum set to const "random".

Comment: `allBoulders` is a function, not an array. You need to call it (and use `await` since it's an async function).

Comment: 1. `upperCount` should be declared outside the loop, not inside. 2. `i+=upperCount;` should not have a semicolon. 3. `i=0, i < allBoulders.length;` should be separated with a semicolon, not with a comma. 4. You probably want to declare your `i` as `let i = 0`

Answer (score 0):

A loop incrementing randomly, using your `randomNum` function, can be done like this:

```js
const randomNum = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

// random increments
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i += randomNum(1, 5)) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

If you want to use the random number inside of the for loop, you can do it like this:

```js
// random increments and use random number inside of for loop
for (let i = 0; i < 20;) {
    // generate random number
    const random = randomNum(1, 5);

    // use it as you like
    console.log(random);

    // increment i manually at the end of the loop
    i += randomNum(1, 5);
}
```

The loop increments in random steps between 1 and 5, not including 5.

Comment: Is it possible to use my randomNum inside the forloop and have the same number generated to use in the forloop and to increment?

Comment: With a small modification, yes. I updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: i got it to work. indeed setting "i" within the loop was the answer. i updated my question with the solution. -cheers!